# SQL Server : what modified my table

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to list all objects like (st procedures, functions, etc. ) that modified a table or a column of this table in last 1 hour?

Comment: If you have any auditing/tracing/etc running for the time period then yes. If not, no, you cannot retrospectively find out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [name],create_date,modify_date 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE modify_date > DATEADD(HH,-1,GETDATE()) 
      AND type IN ('P','U')
```

Comment: This shows a list of objects recently modified.  The question is asking if there is a way to look back and see what procedure or other object modified data in a given table in a period of time.

Comment: Unless you set up such logging in advance, no.